# removing legend in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have some text data I'm trying to graph and am using this code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = label, y = tfidf, color = factor(label), size = tfidf, label = word), data = worddf)+
  geom_text()+
  scale_color_hue(l=40, c=35, guide=FALSE)
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Just as I coded it, the color legend is gone. Good. When I run it through ggplotly, however, the color legend is back:

```
graph <- ggplot(aes(x = label, y = tfidf, color = factor(label), size = tfidf, label = word), data = worddf)+
      geom_text()+
      scale_color_hue(l=40, c=35, guide=FALSE)

ggplotly(graph)
```

[image]

Why can't I get rid of this in plotly?

Comment: Please, could you add to your post the output of `dput(head(worddf))` ?

Comment: @MarcoSandri no problem, I've added it in. I truncated the output because it was so large and therefore SO wouldn't let me post a question with that much code.

Comment: I am sorry but your truncated output of `dput(head(worddf))` is not useful. Could you share a part of your dataset such that it is easy to reproduce the problem in your code ?